# Как применить form validation к элементам массива в codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

от клиента приходят данные в таком виде:

```
  //  $this->input->post() = 
    Array
    (
        [passportData] => array
            (
                [last_name] => fvvvvvv
                [name] => fffffffffffffffff
                [otchestvo] => ffffffffffffff
                [sex] => fffffffffff
                [date_of_birth] => 
                [grajdanstvo] => 
                [series_of_pass] => 
                [num_of_pass] => 
                [issued_by] => 
                [date_of_issue] => 
                [place_of_birth] => 
                [family_status] => 
            )

        [militaryData] => array
            (
                [military_document] => 
                [start_of_duty] => 
                [end_of_duty] => 
                [rank] => 
                [current_position] => 
            )
    }
```

если бы от клиента приходил одномерный массив то я бы написал так:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Фамилия', 'trim|xss_clean', array('xss_clean' => 'XSS в поле %s!', 'required' => 'Поле %s обязательно для заполнения!'));
```

но `$this->input->post();` не содержит непосредственно в себе дочерний элемент под таким названием, так как он располагается в подмассиве Поэтому такая проверка не сработает.

как применить form_validation к элементам во вложенных массивах?

Comment: Попробуйте так $this->form_validation->set_rules('passportData[last_name]', ...);

Comment: http://codeigniter3.info/guide/libraries/form_validation#using-arrays-as-field-names Использование массивов в качестве имен полей